# Parsing JSON response in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

That's the essence of my problem:
It is necessary to list all "file":

```
{
    "results": [{
        "fromuserid": "Anonymous",
        "touserid": "sd68Kbmc02",
        "file": "943easd709bfb2f6",
        "subject": "test",
        "message": "ddd",
        "createdAt": "2013-07-18T20:16:08.023Z",
        "updatedAt": "2013-07-18T20:16:08.023Z",
        "objectId": "bRDvHb4X4M"
    }, {
        "fromuserid": "Anonymous",
        "touserid": "sd68Kbmc02",
        "file": "ef763asd134a8125",
        "subject": "test",
        "message": "ddd",
        "createdAt": "2013-07-18T20:13:56.997Z",
        "updatedAt": "2013-07-18T20:13:56.997Z",
        "objectId": "GaLWnbSFtg"
    }, {
        "fromuserid": "Anonymous",
        "touserid": "sd68Kbmc02",
        "file": "5e7ae0sd5f1b48d0",
        "subject": "etesrtes",
        "message": "dfv fv f",
        "createdAt": "2013-07-18T16:09:20.403Z",
        "updatedAt": "2013-07-18T16:09:20.403Z",
        "objectId": "X83Qd7ctwi"
    }]
}
```

I use:

```
$.getJSON("http://domain.me/user/show_user/name/?callback=?", function(data) {
    $('#tile').html("<a href='http://domain.me/?img=" + data['results'][0]['file'] + "' target='_blank'><img src='http://domain.me/" + data['results'][0]['file'] + ".jpg'/></a>");
});
```

I get one line.
You want to display all lines **data['results'][0]['file']**.

Comment: Can you post an example of the JSON?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.getJSON("http://domain.me/user/show_user/name/?callback=?",
    function(data) 
        {
          var results = [];
          $.each(data['results'], function(i, result) {
            results.push("<a href='http://domain.me/?img=" + result['file'] + "' target='_blank'><img src='http://domain.me/" + result['file'] + ".jpg'/></a>");
          });
          $('#tile').html(results.join(""));
        }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse and loop through the elements of your parsed JSON data, something you can easily do with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)(it is supported in all browsers but IE<9):

```
$.getJSON("http://domain.me/user/show_user/name/?callback=?", function(data) {
    var html = data.results.map(function(item, index, array) {
        return array[index].file;
    });
    $('#tile').html(html.join(", "));
});
```